# pass onChange function already argument checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox where I pass the props to the parent, and I have stopped for the handleChange function and cannot understand what I am doing wrong

---

**My child component**

```
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const Form = (props) => {      
const {values: {debtorIsIndividual},handleChangeCheck } = props 
  return (
    <Checkbox
        checked={debtorIsIndividual}
        onChange={() => handleChangeCheck("debtorIsIndividual")}
        value="debtorIsIndividual"
      />
  )
}
```

### My Parent Component class Component

```
handleChangeCheck = name => ({ target: { checked } }) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: checked });
};

const {  debtorIsIndividual } = this.state;
const values = {
  debtorIsIndividual: debtorIsIndividual
};

return 
  <Form  handleChangeCheck={this.handleChangeCheck} />
```

what am I doing wrong?
Demo https://codesandbox.io/embed/checkbox-material-35kqr

---

P.S. Of course, i can pass a static argument, but I need it to be dynamic, because I will have more than one checkbox in this form

Comment: in child component `this.props.handleChangeCheck`

Comment: `this.props` only when component is class, here `Form` is a function also called `stateless component` in ReactJs. Hence `props.` will work.

Comment: i pass ```handleChangeCheck``` in ```props```,  problem is different, and I do not know what

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are encountering? Also would be helpful to see your Checkbox component

Comment: the ```debtorIsIndividual``` argument is not passed and the handleChangeCheck function does not work because function expects parameter ```name```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to destructure `debtorIsIndividual` from props but yet it doesnt look like you ever passed it as one to the Form component. Also, your `handleChangeCheck()` looks a bit off, you have a function returning another function before setting state? It might be best to just write a codesandbox and share the link with us. The original post looks like its missing a lot of context.

Comment: @Sined4ik try my solution below, that might give you some insight. Additionally, I'll take a look at your sandbox too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue ultimately stems from using an anonymous function in the onChange event-handler in place of directly referencing the desired prop.

```
onChange={() => handleChangeCheck("debtorIsIndividual")}
```

This is likely specific to the material-ui API: https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/

I've created a sandbox for you to give you an idea on how to make this work: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-archimedes-1cewz

Essentially, it looks like you just want to be able to pass up the values from the Checkbox up to the Parent-component. Here's the code as well:

### Parent

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: false,
    age: false,
    docs: false
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    this.setState(
      {
        [name]: checked
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form {...this.state} handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Child

```
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

const Form = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        User Verifed:{" "}
        <Checkbox
          onChange={props.handleOnChange}
          name="name"
          checked={props["name"]}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Age Verifed:{" "}
        <Checkbox
          onChange={props.handleOnChange}
          name="age"
          checked={props["age"]}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Docs Verifed:{" "}
        <Checkbox
          onChange={props.handleOnChange}
          name="docs"
          checked={props["docs"]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is what I need, thank you very much